# How to open webpage inside another webpage without revealing it to the outside world

Tags: javascript, iframe, setcookie

How to open webpage inside another webpage without revealing it to the outside world

I need to trigger open one webpage inside another one just to share one cookie value to the forced triggered page

The triggered url is set to send a cookie parameter which will be then added to the opened page cookie via JS. I need this as a hack as i don't want the user to know that i have opened another webpage.

Suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: same domain or different domain?

Comment: Thanks for leaving a comment @Graficode Studio, the domains are different

Comment: in case of different domains, for recurity reasons, it is not possible to access cookies from another website